# JUnit and WebDriver by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, junit, selenium-webdriver

Im working in IntelliJ and need to add dependency's to Selenum WebDriver and Junit.
I already added the jars (as mentioned in all possible tutorial) to my Project lib.
I can also see them in the project view  - Selenium-java-2.39.0.jar, Selenium-java-2.39.0.srcs.jar, Selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar AND junit-4.11.jar
Nevertheless, my project can not recognized this items (for example 
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend investing some time learning about some dependency management solutions.  Here are my top two selections:

1. Maven
2. Ivy

If using maven, you'd have a `pom.xml` in your project and you'd have something like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

Ivy is very similar, but i won't get into it.  If you need a project to get you started, you can check out [this project](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) ([download here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip)) which is used by Major League Gaming for their selenium framework

Comment: that's my recommendation.  intellij natively supports maven, and will handle all classpath issues

Comment: you can possibly add libraries manually by going to project settings (ctrl+alt+shift+s) -> Libraries, but using Maven is definitely a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you should invest in a dependency management solution, but if you are not forced to use maven, try gradle.
It is way lighter and flexible...
In that case, my dependencies are resume to 1 line:

```
compile "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.2", "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.39.0", "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.39.0"
```

I agree, I could add a second line with a property for the selenium version.

Gradle is really well supported by intellij Idea.

enjoy